# Fancybox displays login form on session timeout cakephp

Tags: cakephp, fancybox

I would like to ask you something I have been struggling.

I have a link wich displays a pdf inside a fancybox modal. Everything works fine until the session expires, the fancybox modal displays the login form.
Do you have any idea of what I can do?: Here is the code I´m using:

index.ctp:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(__(''),                        
                      array(
                        'controller'=>'Search',
                        'action'=>'seepdf',
                        ''                                                      
                      ),          
                        array(
                            "class"=>"glyphicon glyphicon-qrcode fancybox",
                            'data-fancybox-type'=>"iframe"                      
                        )) ?>
```

SearchController.php

```
    public function seepdf() {
    $this->viewClass = 'Media';
    $params = array(
          'id' => '232.pdf',
          'name' => '232',
          'download' => false,
          'extension' => 'pdf', 
          'path' => APP . 'files' . DS 
   );
   $this->set($params);
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I came with, It is not the best way, but It actually works.
I do an ajax call before the fancybox loads to check if the user is logged in, if the user is logged, everything goes normal, but if no user is logged, it redirects to the login page: Here is the code:

index.ctp

```
        var succeed = true;
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'elastic',
        closeEffect : 'elastic',
        padding : 0,
        iframe : {
            preload: false
        },
        beforeLoad: function(){  
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                async: false,           
                url:"Search/isactive/",
                success : function(data) {          
                    if(data !== 'true'){            
                        succeed = false;                                
                    }else{
                        succeed = true;
                    }       
                },
                error : function() {
                    succeed = false;                            
                }
            });  
            if(succeed === false){
                window.location = 'Users/signin'; 
                return false;   
            }   
        }
    });
```

SearchController.php

```
    if ($this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->layout = null ;
    echo json_encode(true);
}else{
    echo json_encode(FALSE);
}
```

I need to add some validations but this is a working code, just in case somebody needs It. If somebody has a better idea, please let me know, Best Regards!